# How to save a CSV file?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have tried to save a file in R as `.csv` but when I run the below function it saves it as a `FILE` instead of a `.csv`. What am I doing wrong?

The `dataframe` is massive with over 4M cells.

```r
write.csv(New_trips_2021, "C:\\x\\x\\x\\Google_Data_Analytics_Project\\Cyclistic_Integrated_V2", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: You need `.csv` at the end i.e. `"C:\x\x\x\Google_Data_Analytics_Project\Cyclistic_Integrated_V2.csv"`

Comment: It is a CSV just does not have any extension. BTW - if only used in R, consider RDS or RData formats for such massive files. You avoid re-parsing from text each time and R formats by default are compressed types, so less footprint on disk.

Comment: could someone post the information in the comments as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when saving a csv file you need to specify the extension `.csv` too in the `write.csv` function.

try this:

```
write.csv(New_trips_2021, "C:\\x\\x\\x\\Google_Data_Analytics_Project\\Cyclistic_Integrated_V2.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Yes, although worth noting that getting the extension right is about *getting your OS to recognize the file correctly*; the contents of the file are the same either way, and many applications would be able to use the file regardless of what it was called/what its extension was.